# Convert seconds to time format

Tags: datetime

I have 10396080 seconds, and I want it to look like this: xxx hours, xxx minutes.
Is there some function for that?

Answer (score 1):

> I have 10396080 seconds, and I want it to look like this: xxx hours, xxx minutes. Is there some function for that?

Not really.  What you want is 10396080 seconds converted to 2887 hours 48 minutes, and I know of now existing function that does that.

There  is [`format_interval()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_interval/7).

```
 $seconds = 10396080;
 $string = format_interval($seconds, 2);
 echo $string;
```

But that will output "4 months 7 hours".

However, the following custom function:

```
 function _hoursminutes($interval, $granularity = 2, $langcode = NULL) {
   $units = array(
    '1 hour|@count hours' => 3600,
    '1 minute|@count minutes' => 60,
    '1 seconds|@count seconds' => 1,
  );  $output = '';
  foreach ($units as $key => $value) {
    $key = explode('|', $key);
    if ($interval >= $value) {
      $output .= ($output ? ' ' : '') .
        format_plural(floor($interval / $value), $key[0], $key[1], array(),
        array('langcode' => $langcode));
      $interval %= $value;
      $granularity--;
    }
    if ($granularity == 0) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return $output ? $output : t('0 second', array(), array('langcode' => $langcode));
}

 $seconds = 10396080;
 $string = _hoursminutes($seconds, 2);
 echo $string;
```

This will output: "2887 hours 48 minutes", which presumably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean - whether you want the hours and minute in the day, or an interval representation of the timestamp.

For the first, there's: [`format_date()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7)

> Formats a date, using a date type or a custom date format string.

e.g.

```
$formatted_date = format_date($timestamp, 'custom', 'H \h\o\u\r\s, m \m\i\n\u\t\e\s');
```

For the second, you might get some use out of [`format_interval`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_interval/7):

> Formats a time interval with the requested granularity.

But it might not do exactly what you want.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about converting an interval (as in `format_interval`), and not a date.

Comment: @FreeRadical Yep was just adding that bit in ;)